# TCL fileutil::magic::mimetype not recognising Microsoft documents or mp3

Tags: ms-word, tcl, mp3, mime-types, file-format

I'm wondering if this is a limitation of `fileutil::magic::mimetype`, or whether something has gotten messed up in my installation. TCLLIB 1.15/TCL 8.5

Take an ordinary Microsoft Word .doc file and pass it to fileutil::magic::mimetype e.g.

```
package require fileutil
package require fileutil::magic::mimetype
set result [fileutil::magic::mimetype "/tmp/test.doc"]
```

It returns empty string. Same for mp3, plus other file formats. It does recognise GIF, PNG, TIFF and other image formats.

Calling `fileutil::fileType` returns `binary` for the Word document.

Standard Linux command `file -i` returns "application/msword" for the same file.

Can anyone confirm if this expected behaviour? I'm a little confused about the relationship between the fileutil and fumagic libraries, so maybe I've broken something in my install around that area.

Comment: I can reproduce this with a conventional tcllib installation. FYI (as someone who has needed file identification in the past) the best MIME type identifier I know of is Apache Tika — a _very_ heavyweight installation as it is Java code — and that's still definitely not perfect.

Comment: Thanks for reproducing @DonalFellows It is disappointing if this is standard behaviour. What seems strange to me is that looking at mimetypes.tcl, it should be able to detect mp3s and Word documents, as it looks quite comprehensive.

Comment: @TrojanName, you're saying it in a way suggesting that `tcllib` is something cast in stone and won't accept any change. That is certainly not true, so I'd at least start from [filing a bug against that package](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/reportlist) or -- better -- work on implementing the required detection code and submit it. I suppose you could "borrow" the idea of such code from that `file` utility itself. Or, say, from the software package Donal referred to.

Comment: @kostix I've taken your advice and submitting a bug report http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/tktview/4adb7c36a35d0c475f8e9bba24ec04984bd8ce2f The point I was making was that .DOC, .MP3 etc are such obvious use cases that I'm guessing that they probably worked at one point in the past, especially seeing as they are listed in mimetypes.tcl